# apple rejected app for not showing ads

Tags: ios, iphone

Hey after 1 week of waiting my app got rejected. The reason from apple i got: Your iTunes Connect settings indicate that your app serves advertisements. However, we were unable to locate ads in your app.

The thing is that i'm sure that my app contain ads. So I suppose apple didn't have internet on when they reviewed. What could the problem possibly be?

Comment: "So I suppose apple didn't have internet on when they reviewed." Wow!  Do you see the ads, not just sure?

Comment: Apple definitely has internet on!

Comment: The screen where you show ads in your app, is that readily accessible? 
Do you see the ads when you have internet on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the App Store review process and policies, and not about programming.

Comment: @Eike I've personally had Apple app review send me screenshots of the app in use upon rejection and said screenshots showed a device with airplane mode enabled.

Comment: You are right Albert, that was just the not so serious response to "I suppose apple didn't have internet on" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a lot of reasons:

1. it's simply review team can't locale steps to reproduce ads in your app.
2. maybe your ads provider do not show ads in the region where review team seat.
3. maybe your ads provider was not available at the time your app was in review.

As an example: my app *third* time rejected the same reason. 
All you should do, imho: send screenshot of ads in your application and steps to locale this ads.

Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I pressed resubmit shortly after by mistake. I've heard this cancels the contact with the resolution center.

Comment: Were you able to sort this out? We just had the same problem and we can't show them the steps, since the ads are only visible sometimes, i.e. when the advertising customers book any campaigns. We can't show 'testing' ads either now, since they would appear also for the users of the app that's currently in the store.

Answer (score 2):

Apple definitely has internet on when they test apps, reason being that many apps have to connect to servers and log on in order to work.

If you're sure your app has ads but Apple can't see them, there might be an issue with your code. Run over your code again to see if there are any errors. Double check your ads provider to see that its working. Also, it may be that the ads are being served in a screen that the team couldn't access, like behind a login. Without any code snippets, I can't give you more detailed advice than that.

If you think the code is right, then it is quite possible that Apple had an issue on their end. Apple's great at responding to developers. I've emailed them countless times, and gotten a call right to my cellphone with someone managing my case personally. Just send them an email with your case number and issue, as well as steps detailing how to view your ads, and they'll respond to you.